# Why is $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ (Linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

This definition of the norm holds for the dot product in Euclidean space. It does not feel like a axiom, because if we defined distance differently we clearly run into problems.  It does not hold for curved space. The simple elementary explanation for this is the cutting of pieces of areas and rearrangement, but this might not work for calculating the distance in curved spaces. To give an example why this kind of argument which involves geometry is not convincing, imagine we drew a square with an inscribed square and proved this by labelling the sides a,b,c. Now do exactly the same thing on a sphere,  and we can conclude exactly the same thing, but $a^2+b^2$  not necessarily $c^2$ on a sphere?

What are the problems encountered if we defined euclidean distance another way? And what is the method of calculating distances in spaces with non zero curvature, and maybe that could shed some light for me on why $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is the definition of distance which works best in euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

In a general normed space, "orthogonal" is meaningless. For orthogonality, you need a dot product. Now let's say that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal with respect to a dot product. Then...

$$||x + y||^2 = \left< x+y, x+y \right> = \overbrace {\left < x, x \right>}^{||x||^2} + \overbrace{\left <x, y \right>}^0 + \overbrace{\left <y, x \right>}^0 + \overbrace{\left <y, y \right>}^{||y||^2} = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of measuring distance that are commonly used- you should research the terms "metric" and "norm" for more information. The reason the Euclidean distance is defined as such is because it is precisely the intuitive and "real-world" result for the distance between points. i.e. the Euclidean distance between the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is the distance I would measure between the points using a ruler (with the appropriate scales). Note that when I say this, I am talking about Euclidean geometry (another phrase you may want to look up) which (if we don't go too deep into the Physics of our Universe) applies to the world around us.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, what you are trying to say is that a^2+b^2 = c^2 is actually an 'empirical result' derived from our daily observations, without a logically rigorous reason that says it cannot be any other?

Comment: Yes. It's essentially just Pythagoras's Theorem. That is the "real-world" distance. There's nothing stopping us from using other distances (and often we do) but this one makes the most sense because it is the "physical" distance so that's why it is the standard one.

Comment: Hmm...if the metric could be chosen arbitrarily, why not consider using the euclidean distance as the definition on a spherical surface? In that case when we draw the triangle spanning one octant of a sphere, we have three 'right angles', and applying the distance formula consecutively on any two sides of this triangle iteratively, we get an inconsistent defintion which will blow up to infinity. Clearly, some definitions of distances 'works better' than others, doesn't it?

Comment: No. The metric applies to specific coordinates and can be visualised by considering the straight line drawn between them in Euclidean space. It doesn't say that given any two curves meeting at right angle that any other curve joining these will satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$ as clearly this can not be true in general